# Centos : su: incorrect password after bash update

Tags: ssh, sudo, centos6.5, su

A few days ago I've updated the bash to patch it agains Shellshock and since then I cannot `su - root` from my regular 'wheelgroupuser' account on Centos 6.5 with WHM.

I'm constantly getting `su: incorrect password` - even though I know for sure that the password is correct.

I have `Password Authorization` disabled and shell is only enabled with ssh keys. The account I'm using to connect to the server is in the `wheelgroup` and was working absolutely fine until the bash update took place. I could easily switch to root user using `su - root` - but not now.

I've also tried `sudo` command - but the same response.

Any idea what needs to be done to solve this problem. I've seen several tickets all over the internet, but none of them is referring to the same scenario as mine.

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: What does `ls -l /etc/shadow` say?

Answer (score 0):

Just curious to know if you can ssh as a root user?

If so, try resetting the /bin/su permissions to root:root!

Comment: also `chmod 4755 /bin/su`

Comment: I can't ssh as root - even if I enable 'SSH Password Authorization' it constantly tells me that I'm using incorrect password, which is really weird considering that I can log in to the WHM as root - just not via ssh. Because of this I can't change permissions etc.

Comment: Can you move the .accesshash which is available in /root/.accesshash and generating a new one via WHM?

Comment: I don't seem to have access to /root directory via whm :( any other ideas?